# How To Resolve Expression must be a list type: String In Apex class

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I wrote this code to  Return an array of characters in reversed order for alphanumeric characters ,but i keep getting error as

**Expression must be a list type: String**

```
            public class assessment {
             public static List<String> reverseAlphaNumericCharacters(String s) {
                List<String> reversedChars = new List<String>();
                for (Integer i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (isAlphaNumeric(s[i])) {
                        reversedChars.add(s[i]);
                    }
                }
                return reversedChars;
            }

            private static Boolean isAlphaNumeric(String c) {
                return ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('0' <= c && c <= '9');
            }

            }
```

Many thanks in advance
Fiona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI, you could perhaps use [String.reverse](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_reverse) and then filter. There is also a [String.isAlphanumeric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isAlphanumeric) method.

I think your problem is that a `String` is not an array of characters as Apex doesn't have a `Char` type. So `s[i]` is not a valid expression. The closest is probably `s.substring(i, i + 1)` that returns a `String` of length one.

Comment: By the way, `String.isAlphanumeric` also includes characters like `ë` and `æ`. If you want Just the "normal" letters, it would be `var.isAlphaNumeric() && var.isAsciiPrintable()`. Or just using `charCodeAt` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Keith's excellent answer, I have some other stuff I'd like point out.

First, note that String comparisons are, by default, case-insensitive. That means that `myVar >= 'a' && myVar <= 'z'` (or using uppercase instead) covers both the lowercase and uppercase scenarios. You could simply check:

```
return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= '0' && c <= '9'
```

Note that `&&` has precedence over `||`, so the parentheses are also unnecessary here (though in real code, I'd probably include them for clarity).

Second, while algorithms like this are somewhat involved, as you've seen here, you can easily do this in Apex with a line of code:

```
public static String reverseAlphaNumericCharacters(String s) {
  return s.reverse().replaceAll('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+','');
}
```

Or, if you really do want the list of strings, you can:

```
public static String[] reverseAlphaNumericCharacters(String s) {
  return s.reverse().replaceAll('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+','').split('');
}
```

We use a regular expression to replace the parts we don't want to keep (non-alphanumeric characters). The only downside is that it can't match more than 1 million replacements, but this should be fine for most use cases.